# Calculating size of opening of a Decanter in order to project 5 gallons of water per second 20 feet in the air vertically?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, estimation, approximations

This question is attempting to determine the size of the opening of a Decanter of Endless Water for our gaming group. We are wanting to hook it up to some impromptu Jerry-rigged technology as either a power source or a refilling unit, and need to know the size of the aperture, and are hoping that the physics SE can answer our question for us, as we are on the low end of mathematical capability.

For those who don't know, a Decanter functions by tapping into the Elemental Plane of Water, and emits a theoretically endless stream of water; basically it's a magical fire hose that will never run out of water. A "round" is six seconds in duration.

> **The rules in question, we are referencing the geyser function**:
>
> Decanter of Endless Water
>
> If the stopper is removed from this ordinary-looking flask and a command word spoken, an amount of fresh or salt water pours out. Separate command words determine the type as well as the volume and velocity.
>
> - "Stream" pours out 1 gallon per round.
> - "Fountain" produces a 5-foot-long stream at 5 gallons per round.
> - **"Geyser" produces a 20-foot-long, 1-foot-wide stream at 30 gallons per round.**
>
> The geyser effect causes considerable back pressure, requiring the holder to make a DC 12 Strength check to avoid being knocked down. The force of the geyser deals 1d4 points of damage but can only affect one target per round. The command word must be spoken to stop it.
>
> Moderate transmutation; CL 9th; Craft Wondrous Item, control water; Price 9,000 gp; Weight 2 lb.

[image: A sample decantur]

Thus, how large would the opening of the Decanter be in order for 5 gallons of water per second to be emitted, forming a plume 20 feet long vertically?

Comment: This depends on the water pressure.

Comment: The fact that the plume is 20 feet long and 5 gallons per second should enable calculus to come up with both size and pressure, since the rate of flow is constant. Possible a set of size and pressure answers.

Comment: Hi nijineko. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Please don't remove the HW&E tag, By this site's policy this **is** a HW&E question, even though it might not be homework in the *strict* sense of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Bernoulli's equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html):

$$p+\frac12 \rho v^2+\rho gh=\text{Constant}$$

At the top of the plume $v=0$, $p=\text{atmospheric pressure}$ and $h=20\:\mathrm{ft}$.

If a plume of water reaches a height $h$, then (ignoring friction and drag):

$$\frac12 \rho v^2=\rho gh$$

$$\implies v=\sqrt{2gh}$$
To calculate opening diameter, use the formula for volumetric throughput $Q_v$::

$$Q_v=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}v$$

Comment: You don't need *p* or *m* to solve the problem.

Comment: I would say that's all Japanese to me, but I speak Japanese. That's easy compared to what you wrote x.x ... I'm math illiterate, I have no idea how solve any of those steps, that's why I asked for the answer! This is not for homework, for the record, this is actually for something from a game I became curious about.

Comment: We try to avoid *pret-a-porter* answers to questions like these.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: the $m$ was a typo, of course. It's been corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: @Gert: Ok, all you need is $g$ and $h$. From that you can get $v$ and $D$. You don't need $\rho$ or $p$. It could be a plume of feathers or water or molten lead.

Comment: @nijineko: the answer has been edited.

Comment: It's a plume of water. From the Decanter of Endless water from Dungeons and Dragons, actually. We're trying to come up with obscure uses for it, and the size of the opening became relevant for one of our, ah, obscure uses. ^^

Comment: Um. So, let's see if I get this right. I use either the first formula or the second or the third to solve for v. Probably the third (?) since you derived it somehow from the first and/or second. Then once I have v, I use the fourth formula to find D, which I'm guessing is diameter? Only what is Q? Or wait, what is g? I don't have that either. And with that third formula, v=0, which just makes g or h equal zero, doesn't it?

Comment: But if v=0, doesn't g or h equal zero too? So I'm not solving for v? Still confused, sorry.

Comment: The kinetic energy of the water, $\frac12 \rho v^2$, is simply converted to potential energy, $\rho gh$. $\frac12 \rho v^2=\rho gh$. Calculate $v$, then $Q_v$.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "project a plume", do you mean vertically upward? If so, that tells you the velocity at the opening. The velocity times the area of the opening equals the volume per second. Now see if you can solve it.